# What subview are all the cell subviews located at? (In the custom cell class)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a class linked to it.

In `awakeFromNib`, (of the custom cell class,) I made a `for in` loop:

```
for (id view in self.subview)
{
    if (view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

When I run it on the simulator, no `textFields` background color changes.

I'm pretty sure, that what I have wrong is: `self.subview`. What should I put in place of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get subviews from self.contentView -

Try the following code

```
for (id view in self.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Give a tag to your view in the cell that contain textfield let suppose tag = 0

for (UIView *view in [self viewWithTag:0].subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I have more than 1 cell